# Model binding is not working on POST request in ASP.NET Core 2 WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

This is my model.

```
public class Patient
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Gender { get; set; }
  public double Age { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Occupation { get; set; }
  public string BloodGroup { get; set; } 
}
```

And this is the POST request intercepted by Fiddler
[image]

And this is my controller.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Patient")]
public class PatientController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Patient patient)
    {
       //Do something with patient
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

My problem is I'm always getting `null` for `patient` in `[FromBody] Patient patient`

**EDIT 1**:
According to ingvar's comment I've made JSON of request body like following:

`{patient: {"name":"Leonardo","gender":"",....,"bloodGroup":""}}`
but this time I gate default value of the properties (eg. `name: ""` and `age: 0`)

**EDIT 2**:
My `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` method in Startup.cs file

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<PatientRepository>().As<IPatientRepository>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
            .As<IUnitOfWork>()
            .WithParameter("connectionString", Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreConnection"));                
        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors(corsPolicyBuilder =>
            corsPolicyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: probably you need to derive api controller or make json looks like {patient: {name:"a" ... }}. Have you tried this?

Comment: I've done and please look at my edit section.

Comment: will it work with capitalized properties (like Name instead of name). also, did you try PatientController : ApiController instead of PatientController : Controller? afaik [frombody] will work for apicontroller only

Comment: Just tried with capitalized properties. It does not work. This is .NET Core 2 and  according to this https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/  you need to use `[FromBody]`

Comment: interesting. do you have `services.AddMvc();` in configureservices (startup.cs)? seems that `[frombody]` should work even for data like `{"name":"Leonardo","gender":"",....,"bloodGroup":""}`...

Comment: Please look at my `Edit 2` section. I'm using `Autofac` for dependency injection.

Answer (score 8):

I spent a whole hour until I found out the problem was that I forgot to add getters and setters after class's properties.

i.e. `{ get; set; }`

Hope to help someone.

Comment: After wasting a day and trying everything I found this answer. This worked.

Comment: @SwanandPangam Glad that i could help

Comment: Same issue here, I thought I was losing my mind. Adding in `{get; set;}` solved it for me

Answer (score 4):

After losing some hair I've found the answer. In the request JSON I'm not sending value of `dateOfBirth`. And that's why model binder is setting the whole `patient` object to `null`. So you need to send proper value of every property.

Comment: If dateOfBirth is optional you should use a nullable DateTime on your model, then the binding should continue to work.